# Create and return a cube using a python script

Tags: python, scripting, mesh, blender-internal-render-engine

In the above code, I need to change the location and the dimension of the cube. I remark that only the dimensions along the  z-axis is changed. How can I change the name of the cube? I have not been able to find out how to do this in the documentation.

```
  import bpy
    from mathutils import Matrix
    D = bpy.data
    C = bpy.context
    scene = C.scene

    # ... lots of code omitted for brevity and clarity

    #------------------House-------------

    #Wall1
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(0.0, 2.0, 1.25))
    bpy.context.object.data.name = "Cube1" #to change the name but it does not work
#here to change the dimensions, but only the z-axis dimension has been changed
    bpy.context.object.dimensions[0] = 4
    bpy.context.object.dimensions[1] = 0.05
    bpy.context.object.dimensions[2] = 2.5
```

Comment: When you assign a string to `bpy.context.object.data.name` it will overwrite the **data name**, see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HtmtO.png instead of the **object name**... Please avoid asking multiple questions. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
bpy.context.object.data.name = "Cube1" #to change the name but it does not work
```

you are changing the name of the MESH datablock.  To change the name of the OBJECT datablock:

```
bpy.context.object.name = "Cube1"
```

I would recommend altering the scale of the object instead of the dimensions.

```
bpy.context.object.scale = (2, 0.025, 1.25)
```

Answer (score 1):

to resize (scaling ) the cube, we can use this function

```
#Wall1
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(0.0, 2.0, 1.25))
#resize the cube
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(4, .05, 2.5))
```

to rename, we can use this instruction

```
# Get the cube object and rename it.
cube = bpy.context.object
cube.name = 'Wall1'
```

but I did not understand why this first way did not work

Comment: Resize function working great